# Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart for Simple Products effects Bundle Products

Tags: magento2.3.4, bundled-product

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Create a Simple Product
2. Set the "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" for that Simple
   Product e.g. to 5
3. Create a Bundle Product
4. Add the Simple Product to an Option of the Bundle Product
5. Open the Bundle Product on Frontend
6. Select the Simple Product and set the desired quantity below the
   defined "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" (e.g. < 5)
7. Try to add the Bundle Product to the Shopping Cart

Expected result
The Bundle Product will be successfully added to the Shopping Cart even when the quantity of the Simple Product is below the defined "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart".

Actual result
The Bundle Product can not be added to the Shopping Cart, the page refreshes and the error message "The fewest you may purchase is %1." is shown.

Comment: issue not generate from my end? its give error message

Comment: https://drops.meetanshi.com/6uuYoN